# Optimize text rendering - CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Text rendering on the navbar, at least on Yosemite's Safari and Firefox, is very bad. Text doesn't show the curve it has but is like thicker and more imperfect.

If I zoom in the webpage, it improves, also if I force focus at any element.

I wouldn't care much about this if it were always regular, but the problem is with the focus. The page doesn't seem to be well designed, and I don't like that impression at all. I'm using Bootstrap framework with Ubuntu typography. This happens at a `font-weight:500`.

Example http://www.bootply.com/Ptp4gXpHAF. Just click the search bar.

This is the difference between what I want and what is rendered:

[image]

The image shows blurred due to upload resolution but I think there is a big difference.

Comment: @misterManSam ok there it is. http://www.bootply.com/Ptp4gXpHAF tap the search bar.

Comment: @misterManSam ok it may just be a thing of the browsers.

Comment: @misterManSam yes I tried it with firefox and it doesn't mark the rendering difference, but safari does show a difference when you click the search bar. I'll try it with Chrome.

Comment: Seems ok on latest stable Safari (OS X Mavericks). Does OS X Yosemite have a alpha / beta Safari build? If so then I wouldn't worry about the rendering problem too much.

Comment: @misterManSam yes I think it's just kind of a build-on-the-go version so it's not finished yet. But chrome also shows a very bad rendering. Look at the picture I posted and thank you.

Comment: So you want it to look like the left `Link Dropdown`? Isn't that without `font-weight: 500`?

Comment: @misterManSam so what font weight should I use for it to be that way?

Comment: I don't know if this is the same situation, but I once had a similar issue, and strangely enough using [`backface-visibility:none;`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_backface-visibility.asp) worked.

Comment: [This is a better resource on backface-visibility](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/) :)

Comment: Shouldn't you just not set a `font-weight`? Or override if you need to with `font-weight: normal`.

Comment: @misterManSam I've set it to 300 and now it works just fine. Thank you all.

Comment: Excellent, post it as an answer with a snippet of CSS and then accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the font-weight to 300. Maybe safari tried to render to higher font weight but when I clicked on it the font-weight property was overridden. Within setting it to 300 it worked just fine.